# Invalid sum on two columns only when performing a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to join two separate columns and sum the results, but im getting invalid results.  I don't want to add the Cash and Sales together.  I just want to add the returned results in the Sales.Amount and Cash.Amount separately.

```
select sum(Sales.Amount) sales,  sum(Cash.Amount) cash from Sales
FULL OUTER JOIN Accounts
ON Accounts.AccountID = Sales.AccountID
FULL OUTER JOIN Cash
ON Accounts.AccountID = Cash.AccountID
where Accounts.AccountID ='1111'
```

When I perform the below search separately it works.

```
select amount from sales where AccountID ='1111'
select amount from cash where AccountID ='1111'
```

I'm performing this query on a Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: edit your question, add the error you're getting

Comment: @Strawberry , you always see these things pretty quick. I didn't even notice the different database types.

Comment: @davejal well I only know one dialect, and full outer join ain't no part of it, so... ;-)

Comment: Do you want a list of accounts with two sums or just the two sums of one account ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I assume that there is an 1-to-N relationship between Accounts and Sales and between Accounts and Cash. The problem that you face is that the two full outer joins repeat the rows in both Sales, so you end up double counting. Try using subqueries instead:

```
SELECT Accounts.AccountId, SalesAmount, CashAmount
FROM Accounts
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT AccountId, SalesAmount = Sum(Amount) FROM Sales GROUP BY AccountId) as Accounts ON Accounts.AccountID = Sales.AccountID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT AccountId, CashAmount = Sum(Amount) FROM Cash GROUP BY AccountId) as Cash ON Accounts.AccountID = Cash.AccountID
WHERE Accounts.AccountID ='1111'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your outer joins are excessive for this purpose.  Probably the simplest way is to use two correlated subqueries:

```
select (select sum(s.Amount) from Sales s where s.AccountId = '1111') as sales,
       (select sum(c.Amount) from Cash c where c.AccountId = '1111') as cash;
```

This will return one row, even when there are no matching rows in either or both tables.  In that case, the corresponding values will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

```
select sum(Sales.Amount) sales,  sum(Cash.Amount) cash from Accounts 
FULL OUTER JOIN Sales
ON Accounts.AccountID = Sales.AccountID
FULL OUTER JOIN Cash
ON Accounts.AccountID = Cash.AccountID
where Accounts.AccountID ='1111'
```